# Options Adblocker ruins website layout (Google Ads disappearing)

Tags: layout, adblock

I'm not sure what to do about this, but on my website I have 3 google ads on a page and when the visitor has adblock enabled it ruins the layout of a part of the website. Not sure how to fix this.
Website: http://riotpointsgenerator.co
Problem: Sidebar on right hand side slides down way too far when adblocker is active

Comment: You're encouraging your customers to use adblock?
That's an interesting strategy...

Comment: Please post only those questions which are programming related.